# Does a series of functions that are 0 a.e. converge uniformly to the function 0 a.e. as well?

Tags: measure-theory

If $f_n = 0$ a.e. for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, does $\sum f_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly a.e. to 0 as well?

Comment: Uniformly, no.  Say for example all $f_n$ are $1$ on the rationals and $0$ on the irrationals.

Comment: @GEdgar: the asker just asked for uniformly a.e. (in the text of the question; the title seems to ask something else).

Comment: @user1770201: do you mean that the series converges uniformly and the limit is 0 a.e., or that the series converges uniformly a.e. to 0?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the set of $x$ such that there is at least one $k$ with $f_k(x) \not = 0$ has measure $0$.